# CDC ODI - Why odi need two views JV$ and JV$D

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

During cdc process odi is creating two views JV$ AND JV$D even both have same structure why odi need two views if both are doing the same work.

Answer (score 0):

In the next paragraphs you will see the diferences (extract from [link](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/understanding-the-odi-jkms-and-how-they-work-with-oracle-goldengate)).

> ***The JV$ view*** is the view that is used in the mappings where you select the option Journalized data only. Records from the J$ table are filtered so that only the following records are returned:
>
> - Only Locked records :JRN_CONSUMED=’1’;
> - If the same PK appears multiple times, only the last entry for that PK (based on the JRN_DATE) is taken into account. Again the logic here is that we want to replicate values as they are currently in the source database. We are not interested in the history of intermediate values that could have existed.
>
> An additional filter is added in the mappings at design time so that only the records for the selected subscriber are consumed from the J$ table, as we saw in figure 5.
>
> ***Similarly to the JV$ view, the JV$D view*** joins the J$ table with the source table on the primary key.  This view shows all changed records, locked or not, but applies the same filter on the JRN_DATE column so that only the last entry is taken into account when the same record has been modified multiple times since the last consumption cycle. It lists the changes for all subscribers.